# paging with angular-repeat (angular 1.2)

Tags: angularjs

ok - so I'm using angular 1.2 to produce something like a report.  It works great, except I want to simulate pages, and that's where it's breaking down.  Imagine I have this:

```html
<page>
   <h1>once of section headings</h1>
   <div ng-repeat="outer in outer_collection">
      <h2>complicated outer collection headers</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="inner in outer.stuff">
        ... block of information ...
      </div>
   </div>
</page>
```

so that works great - and provides one long stream of information blocks.  However - now I want to say something like - create a new page every 6 blocks.  This doesn't work at all.  I tried making a counter and returning something like  using $sce.trustAsHtml - but of course since angular is actually sticking it in the inner html - the  are all being immediately thrown away.

Any ideas would be appreciated.  One big thing is I don't want the headers repeated on subsequent pages.   I've found a way to do it by preprocessing the data into pages, but that means I'm effectively duplicating the angular work in my controller - I'm hoping for a better way?

Comment: *I've found a way to do it by preprocessing the data into pages*: that looks like the obvious, correct way to do it. And that's what a controller is for: provide the correct data structure to the view. Side note: why are you still using AngularJS 1.2? The current version of this abandoned framework is 1.7.8.

Comment: Mapping the data in controller is not duplicating anything and is probably most efficient approch